# Problema con el JavaScript de mi Calculadora

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Problema al dividir los numeros siempre me da INFINITY Pero he estado buscando y no tengo nada para que me de asi. Es que lo queria hacer Robusto.

```js
//Variables
  
  var a;
  var b;
  var c;
  var d;
  var f;

  var operandoa;
  var operandob;
  var operacion;

  var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
  var division = document.getElementById("division");
  var multiplicacion = document.getElementById("multiplicacion");
  var resta = document.getElementById("resta");
  var suma = document.getElementById("suma");
  var verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
  var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
  var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
  var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
  var cuatro = document.getElementById("cuatro");
  var cinco = document.getElementById("cinco");
  var seis = document.getElementById("seis");
  var siete = document.getElementById("siete");
  var ocho = document.getElementById("ocho");
  var nueve = document.getElementById("nueve");
  var cero = document.getElementById("cero");

//Eventos


function init() {
  uno.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "1";
  }
  dos.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "2";
  }
  tres.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "3";
  }
  cuatro.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "4";
  }
  cinco.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "5";
  }  
  seis.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "6";
  }
  siete.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "7";
  }
  ocho.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "8";
  }  
  nueve.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "9";
  }
  cero.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "0";
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  //Resetear
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  reset.onclick = function(e){
    resetear();
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  // Operaciones
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  suma.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "+";
    limpiar1(a);
  }
  resta.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "-";
    limpiar2(b);
  }
  multiplicacion.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "*";
    limpiar3(c);
  }
  division.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "/";
    limpiar4(d);
  }
  verificar.onclick = function(e){
    operandob = resultado.textContent.substr(operandoa.length + 1);
    resolver();
  }
}

function limpiar1(a){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "+";
}
function limpiar2(b){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "-";
}
function limpiar3(c){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "*";
}
function limpiar4(d){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "/";
}

//------------------------------------------------

function resetear(){
  resultado.textContent = "";
  operandob = 0;
  operandob = 0;
  operacion = "";
}

//------------------------------------------------

function resolver(){
  
  var res = "";
  
  switch(operacion){
    case "+":
      res = parseInt(operandoa) + parseInt(operandob);
      break;
    case "-":
      res = parseInt(operandoa) - parseInt(operandob);
      break;
      case "*":
      res = parseInt(operandoa) * parseInt(operandob);
      break;
      case "/":
      
      if (operandob = 0){
        return 0;
      } else {
        res = parseInt(operandoa) / parseInt(operandob);
      }
      break;
  }
  resetear();
  resultado.textContent = res;
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 font-size:22px;
}
li{
 list-style:none;
}
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: white;
 background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 24%, #CCE);
 background-size: cover;
}
#Contenedor{
 width: 290px;
 text-align: center;
 height:auto;
 margin:4px auto;
}
#calculadora{
 width: 234px;
 height: 230px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:2px;
 background-color: #65D277;
}
#resultado{
 margin:8px auto;
 width:95%;
 height:30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-align: right;
 color:#48484D;
 padding: 4px;
 background-color:#fff;
 box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 4px 1px #eee;
}
.Teclas li{
 width:50px;
 height:30px;
 border-radius:3px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#6C73FA;
 cursor:pointer;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px -3px 5px 8px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.Teclas li:hover{
 background-color: #BEF9F0;
 color: #6C73FA;
 transition:0.2s;
}
.Teclas li:active{
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.verificar{
 width: 93.4% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Tarea 2.8 - Kepriel</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 <div id="Contenedor">
  <header class="Titulo">
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="calculadora">
   <header class="top">
    <div id="resultado">0</div>
   </header>
   <ul class="Teclas">
        <li></li>
        <li>DEL</li>
        <li id="reset" onclick="init()">C</li>
        <li></li>
    <li id="siete" onclick="init()">7</li>
    <li id="ocho" onclick="init()">8</li>
    <li id="nueve" onclick="init()">9</li>
    <li id="division"onclick="init()">&frasl;</li>
    <li id="cuatro" onclick="init()">4</li>
    <li id="cinco" onclick="init()">5</li>
    <li id="seis" onclick="init()">6</li>
    <li id="multiplicacion" onclick="init()">*</li>
    <li id="uno" onclick="init()">1</li>
    <li id="dos" onclick="init()">2</li>
    <li id="tres" onclick="init()">3</li>
    <li id="resta" onclick="init()">-</li>
    <li id="cero" onclick="init()">0</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li id="suma" onclick="init()">+</li>
    <li id="verificar" onclick="init()">=</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculadora.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Una vez cambien es el `parseInt` a función ( `parseInt(string)` ). Revisa tu `operandob` ya que siempre es "numero+operador+numero" y el `parseInt()` siempre te dará 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré dos problemas en el código:

1. Para convertir los operandos en enteros deberías utilizar parseInt(xxx), no xxx.parseInt
2. Cuando lees el operandob estás utilizando todo el string ingresado, por ejemplo, si tipeas 6+3, el operandoA es "6" y el operandoB es "6+3", por eso da NaN.  Lo modifiqué para que lea sólo lo que está a la derecha del operador, así: `operandob = resultado.textContent.substr(operandoa.length + 1);.`

Con estos cambios ya funciona tu proyecto (acá te dejo tu código modificado).

Saludos.

```js
//Variables
  
  var a;
  var b;
  var c;
  var d;
  var f;

  var operandoa;
  var operandob;
  var operacion;

  var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
  var division = document.getElementById("division");
  var multiplicacion = document.getElementById("multiplicacion");
  var resta = document.getElementById("resta");
  var suma = document.getElementById("suma");
  var verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
  var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
  var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
  var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
  var cuatro = document.getElementById("cuatro");
  var cinco = document.getElementById("cinco");
  var seis = document.getElementById("seis");
  var siete = document.getElementById("siete");
  var ocho = document.getElementById("ocho");
  var nueve = document.getElementById("nueve");
  var cero = document.getElementById("cero");

//Eventos


function init() {
  uno.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "1";
  }
  dos.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "2";
  }
  tres.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "3";
  }
  cuatro.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "4";
  }
  cinco.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "5";
  }  
  seis.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "6";
  }
  siete.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "7";
  }
  ocho.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "8";
  }  
  nueve.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "9";
  }
  cero.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "0";
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  //Resetear
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  reset.onclick = function(e){
    resetear();
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  // Operaciones
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  suma.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "+";
    limpiar1(a);
  }
  resta.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "-";
    limpiar2(b);
  }
  multiplicacion.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "*";
    limpiar3(c);
  }
  division.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "/";
    limpiar4(d);
  }
  verificar.onclick = function(e){
    operandob = resultado.textContent.substr(operandoa.length + 1);
    resolver();
  }
}

function limpiar1(a){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "+";
}
function limpiar2(b){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "-";
}
function limpiar3(c){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "*";
}
function limpiar4(d){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "/";
}

//------------------------------------------------

function resetear(){
  resultado.textContent = "";
  operandob = 0;
  operandob = 0;
  operacion = "";
}

//------------------------------------------------

function resolver(){
  
  var res = "";
  
  switch(operacion){
    case "+":
      res = parseInt(operandoa) + parseInt(operandob);
      break;
    case "-":
      res = parseInt(operandoa) - parseInt(operandob);
      break;
      case "*":
      res = parseInt(operandoa) * parseInt(operandob);
      break;
      case "/":
      
      if (operandob = 0){
        return 0;
      } else {
        res = parseInt(operandoa) / parseInt(operandob);
      }
      break;
  }
  resetear();
  resultado.textContent = res;
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 font-size:22px;
}
li{
 list-style:none;
}
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: white;
 background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 24%, #CCE);
 background-size: cover;
}
#Contenedor{
 width: 290px;
 text-align: center;
 height:auto;
 margin:4px auto;
}
#calculadora{
 width: 234px;
 height: 230px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:2px;
 background-color: #65D277;
}
#resultado{
 margin:8px auto;
 width:95%;
 height:30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-align: right;
 color:#48484D;
 padding: 4px;
 background-color:#fff;
 box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 4px 1px #eee;
}
.Teclas li{
 width:50px;
 height:30px;
 border-radius:3px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#6C73FA;
 cursor:pointer;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px -3px 5px 8px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.Teclas li:hover{
 background-color: #BEF9F0;
 color: #6C73FA;
 transition:0.2s;
}
.Teclas li:active{
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.verificar{
 width: 93.4% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Tarea 2.8 - Kepriel</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 <div id="Contenedor">
  <header class="Titulo">
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="calculadora">
   <header class="top">
    <div id="resultado">0</div>
   </header>
   <ul class="Teclas">
        <li></li>
        <li>DEL</li>
        <li id="reset" onclick="init()">C</li>
        <li></li>
    <li id="siete" onclick="init()">7</li>
    <li id="ocho" onclick="init()">8</li>
    <li id="nueve" onclick="init()">9</li>
    <li id="division"onclick="init()">/</li>
    <li id="cuatro" onclick="init()">4</li>
    <li id="cinco" onclick="init()">5</li>
    <li id="seis" onclick="init()">6</li>
    <li id="multiplicacion" onclick="init()">*</li>
    <li id="uno" onclick="init()">1</li>
    <li id="dos" onclick="init()">2</li>
    <li id="tres" onclick="init()">3</li>
    <li id="resta" onclick="init()">-</li>
    <li id="cero" onclick="init()">0</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li id="suma" onclick="init()">+</li>
    <li id="verificar" onclick="init()">=</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculadora.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias me ayudo mucho.

Comment: Genial.  Si la respuesta te sirvió, por favor márcala como válida.